# Why US commandos keep whispering terrorists' names?

Tags: plot-explanation, zero-dark-thirty

In the movie, *Zero Dark Thirty* US commandos keep whispering terrorists' names while storming Bin Laden's residence.

To my surprise, the technique works very well, commandos manage to kill several terrorists including Bin Laden.

The terrorists should have been fully aware US commandos are in the house and trying to kill them, why would they respond to commandos whispers and stick their heads out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## This is a movie conceit.

The idea is to draw out Osama Bin Laden from wherever he is hiding but...

### ....it didn't actually happen.

> In his interview this week with ‘The Shooter’ – the US Navy Seal who killed Osama bin Laden – the American journalist Phil Bronstein described a trip to the cinema he and the unnamed man took to watch Zero Dark Thirty.
>
> The film, which tells the story of the hunt for and eventual assassination of the al-Qaeda leader in Abbottabad, Pakistan, claims its action is ‘based on firsthand accounts of actual events’.
>
> ‘The Shooter’, however, had some quibbles. For a start, he said, the actors playing Seal Team 6, the special mission unit that staged the raid on bin Laden’s compound, talked too much. No one would ever yell “Breacher!” when calling for someone to blow down a door, he said - you would just put your fist to your helmet; the recognised signal for a Seal with explosive packets to get to work.
>
> What’s more, when the terrorist leader was finally tracked down, in his bedroom on the third floor of the building, **there was no whispered calling out of his name – “Osama, Osama” – to lure him into the open, as happens in the film**.
>
> "When Osama went down, it was chaos, people screaming. **No one called his name,"** The Shooter told Bronstein.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/film/film-news/9869992/Zero-Dark-Thirty-fact-vs-fiction.html)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, I guess the same applies to Breaking bad, all the techniques of cooking drugs do not work in real life.